# How to pass a list object variable in azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, pipeline

I am using ADO extension task. I need to pass the list object variable in inputs field of ado task where I have two scenarios

examples

1. list with one objects
   inputs:

```
var_example1: | 
           [ 
             { "name": "abc", 
             "location": "abc1", 
             "City": "NY" 
             } 
          ]
```

2. list with two objects

inputs:

```
 var_example2: | 
            [ 
              { "name": "abc", 
              "location": "abc1", 
              "City": "NY" 
              },
              { "name": "xyz", 
              "location": "xyz1", 
              "City": "NY" 
              }  
           ]
```

where observed that when passed variable with single list object(example 1), the variable value is not assigned and variable isn't included in the tasks where as if we pass list variable with two object as shown in example 2, it read the variable and also assign the value correctly.

so could you please help with this.

1. list with one objects
   inputs:

```
 var_example1: | 
            [ 
              { "name": "abc", 
              "location": "abc1", 
              "City": "NY" 
              } 
           ]
```

2. list with two objects

inputs:

```
 var_example2: | 
            [ 
              { "name": "abc", 
              "location": "abc1", 
              "City": "NY" 
              },
              { "name": "xyz", 
              "location": "xyz1", 
              "City": "NY" 
              }  
           ]
```

where observed that when passed variable with single list object(example 1), the variable value is not assigned and variable isn't included in the tasks where as if we pass list variable with two object as shown in example 2, it read the variable and also assign the value correctly.

so could you please help with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.